# Why is there a separate site for Judaism?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

Why is this part of Stack Exchange only for Judaism and not about all religions with tags for every particular?

Comment: [Islam](http://islam.stackexchange.com), [Christian](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/), for example.

Comment: Because religion.  We don't want to be lumped in with all those other heathens. (NOTE: This is a non-discriminatory comment; we all hate each other equally)

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you racist?

Comment: @Alkant: I believe I already explained that.

Comment: @RobW but I can't see them in the bottom of SO page, why? And actually I though that in the bottom is full list of SO sites..

Comment: It's not the full list of sites, only a selection.

Comment: What a lovely opportunity to plug the new [Atheism proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37472/atheism-agnosticism?referrer=FXXAEG7yZKtolt1gitwbPw2) ;P

Comment: @Yannis: That thing is still around?  What incarnation is this one? (pun intended)

Comment: is there a Humanism somewhere?

Comment: When I saw this question's title, I was afraid it was a request to merge Judaism SE with Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wow, the time-to-racism-accusations on this one was *crazy fast*, under 15 minutes.

Answer (score 7):

That might work if religions considered themselves more or less equivalent (as Stack Overflow users consider Javascript and C# to both be programming), but they don't.

Imagine trying to mix a site with tags like [Islam] and [Christianity].  Just wouldn't work.  People would spend all their time arguing.

Comment: Considering the "moderator issues" the Islam site is having, I can't image the issues a plain Religion site would have. We're not trying to start wars over the Internet.

Comment: [Indeed](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site).

Comment: Come on, Javascript isn't programming *runs*

Comment: I've seen C++ vs Java vs C# arguments on SO--they are definitely NOT considered equivalent. Programming languages _are_ a religion, nonbeliever! Embrace this fact for what it is, otherwise you shall be alone and lost when The Great Segfault occurs. Repaint now!

Comment: @Manishearth The language choice is a minor issue. People may tease each other about it, but nobody takes it seriously. Whether the opening brace goes on the same line or on the next, _that_ is religion.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Now that's just silly. The opening brace obviously goes on the same line. :P

Comment: @Manishearth You know that, and I know that, but there are unbelieving heathens out there that need to be brought the light.

Answer (score 6):

There *was* a proposal to create a [general religion SE site on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16966/religion), but it failed to gain enough momentum to make it into a site. The Judaism site itself started as a [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22435/jewish-life-and-learning) as well, but unlike the general religion topic, it did gain enough traction, all the way past beta to graduation.

Apart from [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), there are also sites for discussing [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) and [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/) (both in Beta). Additional proposals exist for sites to discuss [Hinduism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29980/hinduism) and [Buddhism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism).

You are [actively encouraged](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/closing-two-year-proposals) to reopen the proposal, if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: but I can't see them in the bottom of SO page, why? And actually I though that in the bottom is full list of SO sites..

Comment: @Alkant: on SO and graduated sites, you only see *other* graduated sites. In the footer of beta sites, you only see *other* beta sites. To see them all together, go to http://stackexchange.com/sites.

Comment: Just a note: afaik Judaism started out as a SE 1.0 site (which is why they have a custom name), and then went through A51. Not sure on the specifics though.